# How to display Chinese characters in ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding

maybe anyone have ideas of how to display **[Chinese characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character)** in the **ListView control** ?

Comment: What problems do you have exactly?

Comment: It displays "???????" instead of Chinese characters. 
Thats, I think, is the main problem.

Comment: What windows version? You could try going into Control Panel and setting region to China PRC to see if it works on a system level.

Comment: I normally do that to check time/date, if they work then it should work in your app.

Comment: Lukas: Does saving your source files as Unicode (UTF-8, UTF-16, whatever) help? Both .NET and the Windows API should support Unicode just fine. Explorer itself is just a glorified ListView and it has no problems displaying files with CJK in them.

Comment: I'm importing text data (lines) to ListView from Clipboard. Still can't figure out why it does not displays thous characters.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm currently tasked with ensuring a listview in our app displays non Latin characters and I'm seeing square boxes.

Comment: nop, I could not find a solution. If you will find smth, let me know, I'm still interested of how to do that.

Comment: My problem was I was using the Arial font and not Arial Unicode MS.  Once I changed the font of my dialog things started working.  Hope it is that easy for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have Chinese character capabilities on your actual machine and browser:

http://www.jp41.com/internet-explorer/chinese/

If you've done that and it's still a problem, perhaps you are getting data from a database that has been input as Chinese, but the data type on the relevant column isn't Unicode. In which case make change the data type to for example, **n**varchar.